# Problema API skydropx

Tags: api

Estoy consumiendo el API de paquetería de la empresa Skydropx, puedo hacer correctamente la cotización de un envío tal como se documenta en su página. El problema es al momento de querer generar una guía, genero el JSON mediante PHP y posteriormente utilizo CURL para mandarlo pero siempre me regresa un error indicándome que todo el JSON que mande mediante POST esta vacío, el código es:

```
$cotiza = array(
    'address_from' => array(
        'province' =>"Ciudad de Mexico",
        'city' =>"Ciudad de Mexico",
        'name' =>"Envios Transversal",
        'zip' =>"14370",
        'country' =>"Mexico",
        'address1' =>"Avenida Acuducto 115",
        'company' =>"Grupo Transversal",
        'address2' =>"San Lorenzo Huipulco",
        'phone' =>"44358915",
        'email' =>"envios1@grupotransversal.mx",
        'parcels' => array(
            'weight' =>5,
            'distance_unit' =>"CM",
            'mass_unit' =>"KG",
            'height' =>$altura,
            'width' =>26,
            'length' =>21
        ),
        'address_to' => array(
            'province' =>$estado,
            'city' =>$city,
            'name' =>$FullName,
            'zip' =>$cp,
            'country' =>"Mexico",
            'address1' =>$Direccion1,
            'company' =>"",
            'address2' =>$col,
            'phone' =>$telefono,
            'email' =>$email,
            'references' =>$ref,
            'contents' =>"Productos Promocionales"
        ),
    ),
);
```

Y lo convierto a JSON mediante `$cargaPaga = json_encode($cotiza);`

El código CURL es:

```
$url = "https://api-demo.skydropx.com/v1/quotations";
$key = "Mi Clave del API";
$ch = curl_init($url);
$header = array();
$header[] = 'Content-type: application/json'; 
$header[] = 'Authorization: Token token='.$key;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//Agregao el array o JSON a POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $cargaPaga);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$resultado = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($resultado);
curl_close($ch);
```

El API esta documentado en: https://skydropx.github.io/api-doc/#create-a-shipment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

por si aún te sirve la respuesta, PARCELS no debe ir dentro del array de ADDRESS_FROM, te adjunto la corrección a tu estructura

```
<?php

 $cotiza = array(
    'address_from' => array(
    'province' =>"Ciudad de Mexico",
    'city' =>"Ciudad de Mexico",
    'name' =>"Envios Transversal",
    'zip' =>"14370",
    'country' =>"Mexico",
    'address1' =>"Avenida Acuducto 115",
    'company' =>"Grupo Transversal",
    'address2' =>"San Lorenzo Huipulco",
    'phone' =>"44358915",
    'email' =>"envios1@grupotransversal.mx",
),
'parcels' => array(
    array(
    'weight' =>5,
    'distance_unit' =>"CM",
    'mass_unit' =>"KG",
    'height' =>10,
    'width' =>26,
    'length' =>21
    )
),
'address_to' => array(
    'province' =>'estado',
    'city' =>'ciudad',
    'name' => 'algun nombre',
    'zip' => '30640',
    'country' =>"Mexico",
    'address1' => 'calle zarco',
    'company' => "casa",
    'address2' => 'colonia centro por ejemplo',
    'phone' => '1231231231',
    'email' => 'email@gmail.com',
    'references' => 'asdfasdfasdf',
    'contents' =>"Productos Promocionales"
  ),
);
$data = json_encode($cotiza);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-demo.skydropx.com/v1/shipments');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Token token=<<TU TOKEN>>';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
   echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}else{
   echo $result;
}
curl_close($ch);
```